# Is there a canon reason/backstory for why Filch is employed by Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

Argus Filch seems to be singularly unsuited as Hogwarts caretaker.

He's not good at either his real job (cleaning up), being a Squib and thus unable to deal with any and all magical messes - never mind dealing with Peeves' ones; or his self-appointed job (discipline), given all the stuff students get by him.

He's also not exactly a good staff fit for a school run by Albus Dumbldore (what with his insatiable thirst for medieval torture of students for minor offenses).

**Why exactly did Dumbledore keep him around and not replace with someone better at his job?**

I'm looking for book canon/JKR answers.

Comment: He's a janitor... Do we need book or author-interview canon to justify a squib being a janitor? Wasn't there some mention of people feeling sorry for him/his family?

Comment: I always assumed it was because Dumbledore has a soft-spot for those who would be outcast from 'normal' wizard society; Hagrid is the most obvious example of this, but Remus Lupin is another. This is my read from the text, not a specific 'canon' answer so I'm putting it as a comment for now.

Comment: I didn't think he was summarily bad at his day job, even though he couldn't get rid of the swamp Fred and George left on the fifth floor (no magic!). He seemed to be hyper-vigilant about cleaning and harangued anyone who made a mess in the castle.

Comment: Unsuited?! Just look at Hagrid >:( - FILCH FOR JANITOR!!!

Comment: @Omega - Hagrid was an excellent warden and groundskeeper. He wasn't even a bad Magical Creatures instructor, with caveats.

Comment: I think this [meme](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/12/cf/b0/12cfb08d8eeb5090c811e8837d3507d9.jpg) applies...

Answer (score 6):

As far as I could tell, there was no solid reason why he was hired or stayed on at Hogwards--just that he had been there for quite a long time as the caretaker of the school.

> Argus Filch was a Squib and the caretaker of Hogwarts School of
>   Witchcraft and Wizardry since around 1973.

http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Argus_Filch

Anything else is just speculation, but the common understanding is what @Katey HW stated in the comments.

> I always assumed it was because Dumbledore has a soft-spot for those who would be outcast from 'normal' wizard society; Hagrid is the most obvious example of this, but Remus Lupin is another. This is my read from the text, not a specific 'canon' answer